# changedFieldIndicator change on every commit

Tags: field, config, fieldtypes, projectconfig, git

When we're making changes to the Craft config, `changedFieldIndicator` is often the culprit of many changes, and makes pull requests "larger" or more complicated than they need to be.

Is this expected or is there a way to avoid this?

[image: changedFieldIndicator]

Answer (score 2):

We're seeing this issue in relation to the [Super Table](https://plugins.craftcms.com/super-table) plugin. This one generates a new `changedFieldIndicator` every time a super table block type is saved. If a super table field inside a matrix block is changed, the matrix block gets a new `changedFieldIndicator` as well, so saving a matrix field with some super table fields inside it results in a lot of noise in every pull request.

I've [raised this issue](https://github.com/verbb/super-table/issues/500) in the Super Table GitHub repository. If you're seeing the same issue, please upvote it or provide additional information if I've missed anything.

https://github.com/verbb/super-table/issues/500